# How to change the body background color dynamically in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux

I would like to change the backgroundColor of the body in some pages.
The color which I have to set is in store redux. But it seems that he don't know it when he pass in componentDidMount() function.

My code :

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.list(this.props.match.params.page && decodeURIComponent(this.props.match.params.page));
    this.props.list_admin();
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.props.data_admin.backgroundColorFirst;
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.reset();
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = null;
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    data_admin: state.admin.list.data,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    list_admin: (admin) => dispatch(list_admin(admin)),
    reset: () => {
      dispatch(reset());
      dispatch(success(null));
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List);
```

So, is it possible to apply style on body when the color is set in props 'data_admin' ?

Thank for your help

Comment: your code seems to be correct, only issue that you could faced is will component is mounting at that time  this.props.data_admin.backgroundColorFirst is null. So please put a logger and check the value of this.props.data_admin.backgroundColorFirst. And if it changing after mounting and you want a dynamic behavior, you can look into componentWillReceiveProps method. I hope this would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution, Redux or not, only changes the background on initial mount and unmount, not when `props` change.

The [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle function is a good candidate to be doing your

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.props.data_admin.backgroundColorFirst;
```

as well.

Comment: Hello @AKX, it's working nicely thanks ! I just had to add an if condition surely because componentDidUpdate() is called before data_admin prop is hydrated. And for those who seek to do the same thing, don't forget to add document.body.style.backgroundColor = null; in componentWillUnmount() function